# remix form disable submit without useState

Tags: reactjs, forms, server-side-rendering, remix.run

Using remix form
Is there a way to disable the submit button without using state?

e.g. (this is only way I know how to do this...)

```type
<Form method="post">
  <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} value={value} />
  <button type="submit" disabled={value.length < 2}>Submit</button>
</Form>
```

I like that in remix we can remove a lot of the useState stuff, is it possible to achieve this here as well?

Comment: I think your solution is fine. You ultimately need a controlled component (where the form value state is in JS, not the browser DOM) because you need to use the value outside of the input so useState is the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `Form` component

```
// for some reason they use `useTransition as useNavigation`
// https://remix-forms.seasoned.cc/get-started

import { Form, useTransition as useNavigation } from "@remix-run/react";

const navigation = useNavigation();
const isSubmitting = navigation.state === "submitting";


<button disabled={isSubmitting}>Submit</button>
```

Comment: useTransition is the original name. They renamed to useNavigation in 1.10 to prevent confusion with React’s useTransition hook.

Comment: this disables the form only when submitting

Comment: @nadiTime there is no specific Form feature in this manner. because no needed since we have `useState`